# How to control physical buttons

Tags: mosfet

I want to replace physical keyboard with raspberry touchscreen. 
Is there any IC that can make contact between any PIN, like keyboard does?
Keyboard is connect to GAL22V10, but I don't wanna mess with that.

[image]

Comment: Use some analogue switches.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any IC that can make contact between any PIN, like keyboard
>   does?

You could use what is know as an analogue cross-point switch: -

[image]

The above is the block diagram of the MT8809 made by Microsemi. It basically works like this: -

[image]

You could make it from analogue switches also. Before the full digital revolution these types of devices replaced the old strowger relays used in telephone exchanges - basically 8 telephone lines can be routed to 8 other lines thus a massive matrix was built to form a telephone exchange.

ADI make one too: -

[image]

They also make an 8x8 type called ADG2188. See ADI's offerings [here](http://www.analog.com/en/products/switches-multiplexers/unbuffered-analog-crosspoint-arrays.html)

Comment: No, just 10 wires and 18 switches.

Comment: @ZoranDobrosavljevic do you expect to find a chip that exactly matches 4 wires in and 6 wires out? Use a bit of imagination.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make contact between a particular keyboard row and column (simulating a single key press), you could use a multiplexer and a demultiplexer. The schematic below assumes that the keyboard controller drives row lines during a scan and checks column lines to detect keypresses.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3V3nO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(I didn't find a DMX symbol in the editor, so I just flipped a MUX symbol)

This schematic connects any `KBD_ROW` to any `KBD_COL`, according to `KEY_CODE` provided. It's not exactly the same as "to make contact", but enough to fool a typical keyboard controller.

Comment: This only works assuming the buttons work with digital logic levels though. And that you assume that there is next to no current present, which is often not the case either.

Comment: @Lundin Virtually all keyboards are built with microcontrollers, so the first assumption is most likely true. I fail to understand why should there be "next to no current" though.

Comment: Depends on what you mean with "keyboard". If you mean the thing in front of your PC, then your answer is fine. If you mean any form of panel with keys on it, in any environment, then there are lots of other considerations. An analog switch would be a much more generic solution, as it doesn't limit what kind of signal that is used by the buttons. Industrial control panels for example, might use the very same matrix solution as you describe, but they could use any form of signals: current levels, voltage levels, PWM, voltage pulses etc etc.

Comment: @Lundin What would be the use of a keyboard with exotic scanning signals? Do you have any examples of such keyboards? Also, I don't disagree with you: my solution is less generic (but probably much cheaper).

Comment: To provide reliable electronics in tough environments. Currents are commonly used when you expect long wires or when you wish to improve immunity, PWM are commonly be used when directly controlling various types of hardware (motors, valves etc), pulses are commonly used when encoders are present. And so on. It is not really "exotic", it is everyday industrial electronics. For example, take a look at how all the buttons in your car are designed.

Comment: I seriously doubt a project mentioning raspberry is meant for such environments.

Comment: Also, "take a look at how all the buttons in your car are designed" really sounds like a polite way to say "get lost". Or do you really know a place where I could get detailed car schematics?

Comment: Well cars might be a bad example, but I would suspect they mostly design them with a MOSET power switch ("high side driver") with 12VDC, and then on the reader side put two resistors to form a simple voltage divider designed to drive just enough current through the button, as the main concerns will be oxide and moisture. Likely, the microcontroller drives the MOSFET high only during the point when it is about to sample the buttons. The question was tagged MOSFET, which is how I ended up here in the first place :) Indeed Raspberry pie is probably not meant to be used in outdoor environments.

Comment: The project is to replace phisical keyboard and lcd on old coffe mashine with 24" display, touch foil, and web app on RPi. Everything is inside mashine. I can make "button pressed" just with short on two pins, so I guess there is no microcontroller.

Comment: My first idea was relay shield, but I need 18 relays, then I thought to use MOSFET like FET shield, finally I confuse myself.